# Select em MySql

Tags: mysql, select

Tenho 2 tabelas
cidade:
id/idPrefeito/idVice
pessoa:
Id/nome
O select a seguir busca pra min o nome da cidade e o nome do Prefeito e seu vice...

```sql
SELECT cidade.nome, 
       ppref.nome as Prefeito, 
       pvice.nome AS Vice
FROM cidade
JOIN pessoa ppref ON cidade.idPrefeito = ppref.id
JOIN pessoa pvice ON cidade.idVice = pvice.id;
```

porém quando um dos dois dados esta nulo ele não retorna nada, como faço para que Caso idprefeito e/ou idvice seja igual a null ele retorne "Vago" e continue trazendo o restante ??

Comment: Troque o `INNER JOIN`, implícito quando você especifica apenas `JOIN`, por `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Para que seja exibido "Vago" caso o campo seja NULL utilize: `COALESCE(ppref.nome, 'Vago') as Prefeito`, idem para `pvice.nome`.

Comment: Como ficaria pra encaixar nesse select um WHERE nomedoPrefeito = nomeinformado ?

Comment: Mas trazendo ainda os mesmos dados da mesma forma, apenas adicionando um "filtro"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o `LEFT OUTER JOIN` para trazer os dados, mesmo quando um deles estiver `NULL`:

```
SELECT cidade.nome, 
       ppref.nome as Prefeito, 
       pvice.nome AS Vice
FROM cidade
LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoa ppref ON cidade.idPrefeito = ppref.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN pessoa pvice ON cidade.idVice = pvice.id;
```